# What are the levels of monitoring and their importance?

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring

We are going through a process of change in our IT Operations Management. One of the items we are trying to improve is our monitoring of our infrastructure.

So far I've been thinking of only 3 levels of monitoring and I believe that one tool can not do all very well.

To hire such tools in the market, we are in the process of listing these levels of monitoring, what is the relevance of this monitoring for the business and applications that achieve our objectives.

I believe to date that we have 3 macro levels of infrastructure monitoring:

1) Application Level

- APM softwares

2) Asset Level (Hardware, VMs, OS)

3) Network Level

- NMS softwares

Is my thinking correct?
Are there other levels of monitoring? We do not have microservices or containers, but I would like this to be a generic post.
What tools are currently on the market that will monitor each level?

Comment: You also need external monitoring.  Some APM products might cover that aspect as well.  If your business involves user traffic coming in through web or mobile apps, you may also need RUM - real user monitoring - to optimize your UI performance.

Answer (score 1):

In our environment we use Appdynamics and logz.io for all levels of monitoring and it's a best tool,

Basically it monitor it for all levels,

1. Databse
2. Application especially works well on Java based services
3. Servers, containers
4. remote services
5. Business transactions
6. service endpoints, etc.,

Also it monitors all the components like, CPU, Memory, Load average, Network errors per minute, Network utilization, top 10 process usage of CPU and Memory.

All monitoring you can get it in the graph format.